# How to induce charge in glass bubble particles ?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, particle-physics, induction

I am trying to induce charge ( + or - ) in the glass bubble particles ( manufacturer 3M 25-32 micrometer) . Can anyone tell me how to effectively charge them. I have tried placing these particles in a Aluminium plate which i placed at certain potential difference, but this is giving only negative charge to the particles .

Thanks

Comment: Do they have to be glass?

Comment: They can be of metal as well. I have both glass and metallic aluminium particles.

Answer (score 0):

You could try spraying them with an ion wind from a charged needle. If you need an interior rather than surface charge then you will probably need to hit them with a beam of charged particles of enough energy to penetrate to the interior. The easiest would be to charge them negatively using an electron beam or beta emitting radio isotope. How long they would retain the charge is another matter.

Comment: Is there any other way through which we can charge these particles. Also, I have some metallic particles with me and they are also not getting charged when placed in an AL Plate. And I only want surface charges by the way.

Comment: If you only want surface charges then ion wind on glass is probably the simplest approach. However, the static charge will not be very great and will dissipate rapidly under certain environmental conditions eg moist air. What is the application?

Comment: BTW, if you do not need monopolar you could look at electret materials

Comment: I want to pass particles moving in a turbulent flow through an electric field and see whether they are getting charged or not. For that I am right now checking the electric field ( whether it is working properly or not). So, for that I need some charge particles so that they get deflected when certain amount of electric field is applied. I am constantly getting negative charge on the particles even if i connect +ive electrode to the plate (in which particles are kept). I want to see the behavior of +ive charge particles as well and Hence, I am asking this question.

Comment: Maybe this might help http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triboelectric_effect

Comment: If i rub glass particles with paper will there be any charge induction in glass particles ?